# How do I limit the use of <br/> in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a textarea, basically I want to allow the user to use line breaks but I do not want them to use it more than 4x for specific reason. How do I achieve this? Below is an example of what I want to achieve.

```
<p  class="custom_text">

text 1
<br>
text 2
<br>
text 3
<br>
text 4
<br> - START REMOVING ALL THE <br> STARTING FROM HERE
text 5
<br>
text 6
<br>
text 7
<br>
text 8

</p>
```

Comment: There is no `textarea` in your code.

Comment: You are right, but this is the outcome whenever a user input something on the textarea. Do I still need to include it?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question. So it would reproduce `textarea`, input, and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('#whatever .specific-class').length;` or `$('#whatever .specific-class').length;` (jquery) to get the amount of specific classes. Add the same class to all of your `<br>` and add a functionality to your event handler that checks if 
class.length is === 4, if its 4, have a different flow of actions that don't put anymore breaks, or notify the user, or whatever you want to do.

Comment: This is not a bad idea at all, however once you implemented a class name for all <br>. How do you limit them to 4 only?

Comment: OK,  but just to clarify mine, you would simply add an if/else statement that checks for the amount of breaks that there's currently inserted, while its <= 4, allow for them to be inserted, otherwise, don't allow it/notify the user

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer

```
var t=0;   
    text = text.replace(/<br>/g, function (match) {
      t++;
      return (t >= 4) ? "" : match;
    });

alert(text);
```

Comment: You should really accept your own answer (when you can).

Comment: Will do. I just have to wait 2 more days to do that.